# How to Display Image Edit Button on media uploader for non-admin users from frontend in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the wordpress media uploader to upload images from frontend. It's working fine. Now I want to enable images cropping function for this uploader. but I don't know how to display wordpress edit image button on this. Is it possible? Anyone please help me to do this.
My code for media uploder is:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" class="process_custom_images" id="process_custom_images">
<button class="button button_style set_custom_images"><span><i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><?php _e( 'Upload Image'); ?></button>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var $ = jQuery;
if ($('.set_custom_images').length > 0) {
    if ( typeof wp !== 'undefined' && wp.media && wp.media.editor) {
        $(document).on('click', '.set_custom_images', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var button = $(this);
            var id = button.prev();
            wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment) {
                id.val(attachment.id);
            };
            wp.media.editor.open(button);
            return false;
        });
    }
}
});
</script>
```